# ADT returns error when I changed the Project Build Target

Tags: android, adt

I recently changed my Project Build Target from *Android 2.3.3* to *Google APIs* and from this time I get an error from the `values-v11` folder which says

> error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name  'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.

Maybe I need to remove that folder or there is something else I can do to include this theme in my app

Answer (score 1):

2.3.3 is doesn't have the Holo styles and resources. So, it will give this error.

You have two options:

1. Remove those styles
2. Switch to latest SDK

BTW, any specific reason of using build target  as 2.3.3? You could have the target set to the latest version, and run your app on 2.3.3 as well.

Comment: I need to add a map activity in my android app so as I noticed the android 2.3.3 does not support this feature

Comment: That should do. You could also remove the specific styles or change their parents to something that are available on 2.3.3